# How do I lock in a cell in a list into a formula, so that the formula won't lose it when I edit the list?

Tags: excel

I have a list of employees with their stats, its the kind of job where people come and go. Now I'm good with data and the numbers make all the sense in the world to me. Management not so much. So I present the data in a separate worksheet in a much "nicer" way. I want to delete someone in the list in a way that if I refer to a cell in the "nicer" worksheet, B64 for example for lets say "sally" if i delete a row above it. Sally's data becomes "john" data and the other worksheet is messed up. How do I avoid that.

Comment: I'm great in grammar as you can see

Comment: poor sally, I hope he/she found a better job. It's not clear how your list looks like, so maybe a sample screenshot will help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the indirect() function

If you want to cell reference A1 of sheet1 in nicer sheet, then usually we reference it us `=+Sheet1!A1`. But to avoid the `#REF!` problem on deletion use the indirect function as below

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&CELL("address",A1))
```

now even if you delete rows in sheet1, the nicer sheet will not get messed up; it will reference the cells correctly in the order how it is in sheet1 correctly in nicer sheet without any `#REF!`